# 404 error page page not shown in some conditions

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp

When my path is

```
hostname/some_file.jsp
```

ErrorPage404.jsp is displayed

But when my path is any one of following

```
hostname/some_file.html
hostname/some_file_path
hostname/unknown_path/some_file_path
hostname/unknown_path/some_file.html
```

ErrorPage404.jsp is not displayed

I have mapped ErrorPage404.jsp  in web.xml in following manner

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/Entry/ErrorPage404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is displayed instead of your custom error page?

Comment: There exists actually a file `some_file.jsp` in the context root? Also, what happens when ErrorPage404.jsp is not displayed?

Comment: Header and footer with no body is displayed, when error page is not displayed. There is no some_file.jsp present

Comment: So your core issue is that there's actually no 404 status returned?

Comment: I can see 404 in console